# ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved. Unable to start activity bc need Theme.AppCombat. Fix Dependencies in android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've run into an issue when making an android app in Eclipse, while following Google's developer guide. When I first created my package I had its minSdkVersion="8" I think I chose Gingerbread. Later on, I decided I wanted to change the min support to "11". So I went to the AndroidManifest.xml and changed 8 to 9. Everything was fine until I go to Project>clean.

After the cleaning, my project gave me errors. It won't recognize ActionBarActivity in my classes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

In addition my imports for support.v4 and v7 also give me errors. (Which I think now I won't need since my minSdkVer=11, but when I delete them I still have the errors)

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

In my console, I get mismatch dependencies as follows:

```
[2014-06-19 20:45:22 - SampleApp] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp] Versions found are:
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp] Path: C:\Users\Laajue\Dropbox\JavaWorkspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp]   Length: 621451
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp]   SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp] Path: C:\Users\Laajue\Dropbox\JavaWorkspace\SampleApp\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp]   Length: 648327
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp]   SHA-1: ded9acc6a9792b8f1afc470f0c9cd36d178914cd
[2014-06-19 20:45:25 - SampleApp] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I believe the issue has to do with when I changed the minSdkVersion from 8 to 11 in the manifest, meaning there are more things I should do, but I don't know what that is.
BTW, in my "libs" folder I only have android-support-v4.jar. Not sure if I'm supposed to have anything else there, or if I should get rid of that as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide appcompact-v7 as a android library project. Also delete android-support-v4-xxx.jar in either your libs folder or appcompact folder. I usually delete it from the library folders. That way when I add other library I dont need to know from where to delete. 
The error is caused by same jar files having different sha1 fingerprint in your build path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes appcompact_v7 was already created as a library project by default when I first created the app, so it is still there. Great! my problem was fixed when I deleted v4. Thank you! I'll read more on sha1 fingeprints and built paths

Comment: @AlonsoGutiérrez if it works for you mind accepting my answer